# Android <alpha> issues... image blinks?

Tags: android, eclipse, animation, fadein, alpha

My fade in code works properly, but at the end before transitioning to the main .java file it shows the image again for a second. What could I do to fix this?

FadeIn code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<alpha
android:fromAlpha="0.0"
android:toAlpha="1.0"
android:duration="1500">
<alpha
android:startOffset="1500"
android:fromAlpha="1.0"
android:toAlpha="0.0"
android:duration="1500"
>
</alpha>
</alpha>

</set>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the android:visibility="invisible" on the ImageView in your layout. If this doesn't work please post the relavent code from your xml layout, and from your java file.